# Display a VennDiagram in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, venn-diagram

I want to interactively show a `VennDiagram::venn.diagram()` in Shiny R.

However, the function `venn.diagram()` requires a `filename`-attribute as it generates an external TIFF-document.

Thus, what function should I use to generate a venn diagram dynamically based on an user input (`input$SELECTION`)?

I suppose I should use the functions `draw.single.venn`, `draw.triple.venn`, `draw.pairwise.venn`, `draw.quad.venn`, but I do not know in advanced *how many* venns I will need.

```
library(shiny)
library(Venn.Diagram)

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Title"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      checkboxGroupInput(
        "SELECTION",
        label = "Select your subsets",
        choices = list("Web of Science" = "WoS",
                       "Scopus" = "Scopus",
                       "Dimensions" = "Dimensions",
                       "LENS" = "LENS"),
        selected = c("WoS", "Scopus")
      ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("venn")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$venn <- renderPlot({

    data <- list(WoS=c("ff", "gg"), Scopus=c("ff", "gg"), Dimensions=c("ff", "gg"), LENS=c("ff", "gg"))
    
    # select only those elements that are named in input$SELECTION
    data <- data[input$SELECTION]
    
    # this will not work
    venn.diagram(data)
  })
  
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Perhaops [this](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/venn-diagram-with-r-or-rstudio-a-million-ways/) will help?  It suggests you can just set `filename=NULL`...

Comment: Limey, thank you, that's it! By adding the whole `display_venn`-function from that page you linked to, and then writing `display_venn(data)` in my original code (instead of `venn.diagram(data)`, it really works! - - Do you want to write that in a full-fledged response so that I can upvote & accept it?

Comment: Thank you for the offer, but no thank you.  I don't feel a simple "read the documentation" solution is worthy of any credit.  :)

Comment: Well, finding the right spot in a documentation is sometimes a great feat in itself! And it's just about a few virtual points ... and it might help others in the future to immediately see the solution :-) But as you wish!

Comment: @Limey: well, I admire your modesty and probably you may even be right. However, SO is not only about helping anpami, but all the people out there. Please let me encourage you to write it down as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limey posted the correct answer in the comments, drawing from [this source](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/venn-diagram-with-r-or-rstudio-a-million-ways/).

First, I added this function:

```
display_venn <- function(x, ...){
  library(VennDiagram)
  grid.newpage()
  venn_object <- venn.diagram(x, filename = NULL, ...)
  grid.draw(venn_object)
}
```

Secondly, I replaced `venn.diagram(data)` with `display_venn(data)`.