# Shiny: renderPrint a string without [1] and without escape characters

Tags: r, string, shiny, printing, escaping

How do I print a string in Shiny S ...

- without `[1]`,
- without the starting and ending quotation marks `"`,
- and without escape characters?

**Example**:

```
library("shiny")

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("showstring")
  )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$showstring <- renderPrint({
    
    mystring <- "DOI (\"10.3390/ijerph15010052\")"
    
    mystring
    
  })
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Current (bad) outcome:

[image: shiny output that is escaped]

Comment: Use `renderText` rather than `renderPrint`.

Comment: Thanks, Limey - perfect solution. I am embarrassed as the response seemed to be so simple. You should post it as a response so that I can tick it as the correct one and thus 'close' the issue (for possible other users). (But I know [we had this discussion before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66118982/display-a-venndiagram-in-shiny-r), and you do not seem to be so keen to get your virtual points!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer (thanks to Limey in the comments) was to use `renderText` rather than `renderPrint`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the `[1]` and the `""` marks and still need to use the `renderPrint()` function, then use the `cat()` base R function for concatenate and print, as shown in the code below. I needed to use the `renderPrint()` function because the reactive object I was outputting in my App either takes the form, through a conditional if/then, of a complicated list object that can only be shown with `renderPrint()` or a short text string saying something to the effect "more inputs are required to show the table". It was easier for me to combine the two into the same `renderPrint()`, and wrap the text string in `cat()`, than it would have been to set up another conditional with `renderPrint()` for one type of object and `renderText()` for the other type of object.

Code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("showstring")))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$showstring <- renderPrint({
    mystring <- cat("DOI (\"10.3390/ijerph15010052\")")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```